# slicing a numpy array based on specific Boolean indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array (`X`)

```
1   2   3   4
3   4   5   6
5   6   7   8
```

and a Booelan index array (`ind`)

```
0 1 1 0
```

I would like to slice the numpy array based on the index. 
i.e.
The resultant array after silicing should only have columns 2 and 3 (with corresponding index 1):

```
2   3   
4   5   
6   7
```

I tried `X[:,ind]`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Convert `ind` to boolean array before indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert `ind` to a `boolean array`. An easy way to do this is by using `numpy.array()`:

```py
numpy.array(ind, dtype=bool)
```

You can then use `X[:,ind]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `ind` to dtype: `bool`.

This can be done by masking with `ind == 1`.

That is to say,

```
>>> X[:,ind == 1]
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```